# Localhost spits out PHP source code

Tags: php, localhost

I just installed MAMP 2.1.1 on OS X 10.7.4. The MAMP Start page says everything is running.

MySQL is running, I can issue command line commands in Terminal. I tested PHP by typing:

```
php -f testphp.php
```

where testphp.php contained one line of code:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

In the terminal window, this returned the expected - an extensive listing of PHP config info. All appears to be well, but if I direct Safari to a simple PHP page, instead of seeing the page run, I get a listing of its source code!

I built a page whose body is:

```
<body>
Testing PHP:
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
</body>
```

I called it testphp.php. If I go to :

```
localhost/testphp.php
```

I see the source code listing! If I rename the file to `testphp.html`, I see:

```
Testing PHP:
```

but that's all - the line of PHP code produces nothing.

Can anyone explain why my localhost server won't talk PHP?

Answer (score 2):

First:
Are you really going through the server?
Try

```
`http://localhost/testphp.php`
```

Second:
Is the server set up for php?
Is the server set up to read from wherever you have your source file?

Comment: I found most of the answer at
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server

Note that the virtual host configuration didn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: After following the info at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server

Comment: After following instructions athttp://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server

Comment: I am running PHP pages now. I'm having a problem accessing MySQL now, though... but I got PHP fixed!